# Jquery Editor not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working to use jquery editor and tried following code but still i am getting simple text area.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>JQueryEditor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <textarea id="mail"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/jHtmlArea/jHtmlArea.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jHtmlArea-0.8.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#mail").htmlarea();
    });
</script>
```

What I am doing wrong here

Comment: are all scripts rendered correctly?

Comment: Is there any error in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

put the link and script tags inside head and check that all the scripts and css you are referencing exist in ~/scripts.

Comment: I did put those script and css but result is same and all exist in my project and referenced correctly

Comment: When I load the scripts and css from a CDN it works - so, there's something wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to this https://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/? They have very good tutorials there, for example [this](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/07/21/jHtmlArea-The-all-NEW-HTML-WYSIWYG-Editor-for-jQuery)

For me, it looks like the script is not loaded correctly. Try to add a CDN for jquery instead of local. And use foldernames like "scripts" not "Scripts", case sensitive.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jHtmlArea-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="/scripts/jHtmlArea/jHtmlArea.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the JQuery Version 1.9.1
[JQuery 1.9.1](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

Answer (score 0):

Try TinyMCE. It's better maintained than jhtmlarea.

```js
tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script></script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea>Next, get a free TinyMCE Cloud API key!</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```